# Removing an entity and then adding a new one in its place

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

So I'm making a zombie simulation game. What I have is a bunch of players and zombies randomly running around at this point. When a survivor collides with a zombie I want it to remove the survivor and replace it with a zombie, essentially turn him into a zombie.

The collision detection works fine(I'm just using awt rectangles with the intersect method). However I have an array list of zombies, and an array list of survivors. When a collision happens I add the zombie to the list of zombies. Then I remove the survivor from that list. It works for a couple times, and then randomly throws an index out of bounds exception.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13, Size: 13
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at com.caveragestudios.zombiesim.World.update(World.java:53)
    at com.caveragestudios.zombiesim.Main.update(Main.java:93)
    at com.caveragestudios.zombiesim.Main.run(Main.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've tried using advanced for loops, regular for loops, and iterators with a while loop. Nothing seems to be working. This is my code as of right now.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < survivors.size(); i++) {
        Survivor s = survivors.get(i);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < zombies.size(); ii++) {
            Zombie z = zombies.get(ii);
            if (z.bounds.intersects(s.bounds)) {
                zombies.add(new Zombie(s.position, this));
                survivors.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything else appears to be working properly, it's just when I try to modify the lists it sort of messes up and throws an index out of bounds exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've managed to figure this out for myself. With a push in the right direction from Masud. The issue was that I couldn't modify the lists while iterating over them, however I still needed the data from the iterators.

What I did was create two new Lists, one called toRemove to be filled with the colliding survivors. Then one called toAdd to be filled with the colliding zombies.

Then iterated over like normal, but instead of adding and removing from the main lists directly, added them to those new lists. Then after the iteration was done, removed and added those new lists accordingly. This is the final code.

```
    List<Survivor> toRemove = new ArrayList<Survivor>();
    List<Zombie> toAdd = new ArrayList<Zombie>();

    Iterator<Survivor> survIt = survivors.iterator();
    Iterator<Zombie> zombIt = zombies.iterator();
    while (survIt.hasNext()) {
        Survivor s = survIt.next();
        while (zombIt.hasNext()) {
            Zombie z = zombIt.next();
            if (z.bounds.intersects(s.bounds)){
                toAdd.add(new Zombie(s.position, this));
                toRemove.add(s);
                System.out.println("collided");
            }
        }
    }

    for (Survivor s : toRemove) {
        survivors.remove(s);
    }

    for (Zombie z : toAdd) {
        zombies.add(z);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used outer list `survivors` index `i` to inner list `zombies`. Your index variable is wrong at `zombies.get(i)`.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < survivors.size(); i++) {
    Survivor s = survivors.get(i);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < zombies.size(); ii++) {
        Zombie z = zombies.get(ii);// Here use ii instead of i
      //..............
  }
 }
```

---

To remove element from collection use `Iterator.remove`. Change your code like below for safe remove from collection.

```
 Iterator<Survivor > survIt=survivors.iterator();     
 Iterator<Zombie> zombIt=zombies.iterator();
 while(survIt.hasNext()){
       Survivor s=survIt.next();    

         while(zombIt.hasNext()){
           Zombie  z=zombIt.next();

            if (z.bounds.intersects(s.bounds)) {
            zombies.add(new Zombie(s.position, this));

            survIt.remove(); //Use Iterator.remove.

            }                 
        }
  }
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that, lol. However I've changed it, and now instead of working several times and then breaking, it breaks on the first collision. So I'm thinking that wasn't the only issue.

Comment: Darren, Use Iterator.remove to remove element from collection.

Comment: I don't believe you can remove a specific object from the list with that though. I'd have to be using something like while (survivors.iterator().hasNext()). Then it would just get stuck in there and not continue the rest of the program. I tried that and I don't believe it will work.

Comment: Well that throws a ConcurrentModificationException. Which after researching says that you can't modify a list while iterating over it. I think I'm gonna have to take a whole new approach to this completely.